# Построить круг из точек

Tags: java

Всем привет! Нужно построить круг из точек( заполненный), каждая точка будет иметь свое значение и из-за этого  свой оттенок цвета, в результате должен получиться некий рисунок в круге. Сейчас строю примитивно, из центра по углу наклона, и отрисовка с помощью JFreeChar, получается мало точек(соотв. малая точность рисунка) и градусы надо забивать в код. Возник вопрос, может кто знает как проще и эффективнее сделать? Что-то вроде матрицы точек заполнять

Answer (score 1):

Для рисования линий и окружностей используют [алгоритм Брезенхема](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%91%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%8D%D0%BC%D0%B0).

При работе алгоритма вы получите все точки окружности в первом квадранте. Отразив их относительно вертикальной оси, сможете заполнять верхнюю полуокружность, например, сплошным цветом. Если нужен не сплошной цвет, а узор, нужно брать координату каждой точки и преобразовывать её в цвет.

Пример.

Алгоритм Брезенхема строит окружность вокруг центра координат *(0, 0)*. Получив на очередном шаге следующую координату *(x<sub>i</sub>, y<sub>i</sub>)*, можем провести линии от *(-x<sub>i</sub>, y<sub>i</sub>)* к *(x<sub>i</sub>, y<sub>i</sub>)* и от *(-x<sub>i</sub>, -y<sub>i</sub>)* к *(x<sub>i</sub>, -y<sub>i</sub>)* — это даст заполненный круг.

Для узора при рисовании линии от *(-x<sub>i</sub>, y<sub>i</sub>)* к *(x<sub>i</sub>, y<sub>i</sub>)* надо брать каждую отдельную точку для *x<sub>j</sub>* от *-x<sub>i</sub>* до *x<sub>i</sub>* и вычислять её цвет по вашей формуле.

*c = f(x<sub>j</sub>, y<sub>i</sub>)*

Comment: Про алгоритм Брезенхэма читал, но он для построения линий, а мне требуется заполнить окружность точками. То есть получить круг из точек, цвет каждой из которых будет вычислен по формуле.

Comment: @Sergey, пройдите по ссылке в ответе и чуть перемотайте вниз. Там описание **алгоритма Брезенхема для построения окружностей**.

Comment: Добавлю, что принцип построения горизонтальных линий, заполняющих круг, можно использовать не только вкупе с Брезенхэмом, но и просто считать пределы по X для каждого Y вроде `xleft = x0-sqrt(R^2 - (y-y0)^2))`